# Is it wrong to hug a friend of the opposite gender?

Tags: women, culture, reference-request, men, lust

I was listening to a katha and the katha vachak said that in our shastras, it is forbidden even to touch a female wooden toy. In which shastra is it mentioned that you shouldn't touch/hug females?

Where is it said that males should maintain a distance from females?

Answer (score 1):

**[gopatha brahmaNa I.2.4](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in:8443/jspui/handle/10603/151631)** while explaining brahmacharya eulogizes a man who doesn't touch woman :

> *Indeed these five fires are placed in a brahmacharin (vedic student) - two separately in the hands, (one each) in the mouth (and) in the heart and fifth in the lap. In that **he does not touch a woman with**
> **(his) right hand**, thereby he obtains day by day that world which is
> won by those who offer every day. In that **(he does not touch) with
> left hand**, there by he obtains that world which is won by the
> religious mendicants. In that **(he does not touch) with mouth**, thereby
> (he obtains the world) of them who leap into fire. **In that (he does
> not touch) with heart**, thereby (he obtains world) of heroes. In that
> **(he does not touch) with lap**, thereby (he obtains the world ) of
> performers of household sacrifices. **If with these (limbs) he touches a
> woman, he remains without fire, as it were**.*

Comment: Brahmacharya begins with upanayana & ends with samavartana. Since non-brahmanas don't undergo upanayana, this means that they are exempted from these restrictions.