# Is touching a woman (who is not one's wife) sin?

Tags: women, sex

Is touching a woman (who is not one's wife) sin ?
I mean touching in a non-sexual way, like putting one's hand on the shoulder ?

Now-a-days hand-shaking is considered as normal.So, one can't avoid it.

But Is touching a woman sin ? In general.

Is there any such thing written in scripture ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it wrong to hug a friend of the opposite gender?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57326/is-it-wrong-to-hug-a-friend-of-the-opposite-gender)